# TypeScript obtain type for class instance

Tags: typescript, class, typescript-typings, return-type, typeof

I'm using a [library](https://docs.magic.link) that exposes an SDK, but not the type (`UserModule`) of one of the objects (`user`) you can create with it.

```
import { Magic } from 'magic-sdk';

// ...

function useMagicLinkAuthentication() {
  const [magicReady, setMagicReady] = usePromise<Magic>();
  const [isMagicInitialized, setMagicInitialized] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserModule | null>(null);

  // ...

  const signIn = async (email: string) => {
    const magic = await magicReady;

    if (await magic.user.isLoggedIn()) {
      return setUser(magic.user);
    }

    await magic.auth.loginWithMagicLink({ email });
    return setUser(magic.user);
  };

  // ...
}
```

As you can see, I need access to the `UserModule` in `useState` which I have no access to (because I can't do `import { UserModule } from 'magic-sdk';`.

For functions there is `ReturnType`. So if I have a regular function, I can do:

```
export const createFoo = () => { /* ... returns a Foo ... */ } 
export type Foo = ReturnType<typeof createFoo>;
```

Is there an equivalent for classes in TypeScript so that I can access the instance of `new MyClass` and get

```
// broken pseudo-code
export type Foo  = Something<typeof MyClass.foo>
```

?

I need to somehow get `typeof magic.user` aka the `UserModule` type.

Comment: FYI there is a built-in utility type `InstanceType`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype  But it sounds like that's not actually what you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `type` alias from the constructor:

```
type UserModule = Magic['user'];
```